# How to use Bootstrap tab in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am trying to use Bootstrap tab but it is not working in Angular app. It seemed quite easy as used Bootstrap previously but can't work around in this Angular app. It displays content of both the tabs and the links do not work properly.
P.S I am not using NG Bootstrap

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link  " aria-current="page" href="#tab1"  data-toggle="tab">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#tab2"  data-toggle="tab">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>

        <div class="row"">
      <div class="col-lg-4" id="tab1">
            <div class="card mb-4">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
               <h4>Tab 1</h4>
        <p>content</p>
       </div>
             </div>
           </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4" id="tab2">
         <div class="card mb-4">
       <div class="card-body text-center">
        <h4>Tab 2</h4>                     
       <p>Content</p>
               </div>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: How have you installed bootstrap?  (It's not in the angular packages by default)

Comment: Hi , yes I have instal ed it and also have link to the jquery . The div with 'row' has  *ngFor , can that be a reason?

Comment: Probably not, but what's more likely is that you're simply not importing the bootstrap stylesheet anywhere (In your styles.css or angular.json or index.html). [This](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-bootstrap/) may help you!

Comment: I have them added in Angular.json.   "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],

Comment: I copied your code [in a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wcsgdj?file=src/app/app.component.html) and got a `Opening tag "div" not terminated.` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has worked after using the link from CDN for Jquery and Bootstrap.js. So the url of the directory wasn't right.